# No module named 'websockets.legacy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

i'm trying to build a exe with auto-py-to-exe. Exe build successful but now my websocket server
program not working.
If anyone knows the solution for this please let me know.

code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import win32com.client
import win32api
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
import io
import time

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')

ImageFile.MAXBLOCK = 2**20

def left_click(pos_x, pos_y):
  win32api.SetCursorPos((pos_x, pos_y))
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, pos_x, pos_y, 0, 0)
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, pos_x, pos_y, 0, 0)

def right_click(pos_x, pos_y):
  win32api.SetCursorPos((pos_x, pos_y))
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, pos_x, pos_y, 0, 0)
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, pos_x, pos_y, 0, 0)
    
async def echo(websocket, path):
 while True:
    try:
        raw_data = await websocket.recv()
        data = json.loads(raw_data)
        if data['type'] == 'click':
            pos_x = data['x']
            pos_y = data['y']
            if data['click_type'] == 1:
              left_click(pos_x, pos_y)
            elif data['click_type'] == 2:
              left_click(pos_x, pos_y)
              left_click(pos_x, pos_y)
            elif data['click_type'] == 3:
              right_click(pos_x, pos_y)
            else:
              pass
        if data['type'] == 'keydown':
            cmd = ''
            
            if data['shiftKey']:
              cmd += '+'

            if data['ctrlKey']:
              cmd += '^'

            if data['altKey']:
              cmd += '%'

            if len(data['key']) == 1:
              cmd += data['key'].lower()
            else:
              cmd += '{'+data['key'].upper()+'}'

            shell.SendKeys(cmd)
    except websockets.ConnectionClosed as exc:
        pass
    except Exception as ex:
        pass
    try:
        PREV_IMG = None
        hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

        width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
        height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
        left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
        top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)

        # device context
        desktop_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
        img_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(desktop_dc)

        # memory context
        mem_dc = img_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()

        screenshot = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        screenshot.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, width, height)
        mem_dc.SelectObject(screenshot)

        bmpinfo = screenshot.GetInfo()

        # copy into memory 
        mem_dc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), img_dc, (left, top),win32con.SRCCOPY)

        bmpstr = screenshot.GetBitmapBits(True)

        pillow_img = Image.frombytes('RGB',
          (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
          bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX')
        with io.BytesIO()as image_data:
            pillow_img.save(image_data, "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
            image_data_content = image_data.getvalue()

        if image_data_content!= PREV_IMG:
            await websocket.send(image_data_content)
        PREV_IMG = image_data_content
        mem_dc.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.DeleteObject(screenshot.GetHandle())

    except websockets.ConnectionClosed as exc:
        pass
    except Exception as ex:
        pass

    

async def main():
  async with websockets.serve(echo, "", 9999):
    await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

This program is made for rdp and vnc, which becomes a server using websockets and then the client can access the computer by connecting to it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Go to advanced and add hidden imports (websockets.legacy) until it succeeds. You will probably need to add other hidden imports as well (the ones it fails to find)
[image]

Comment: you didn't provide solution to the root problem "No module named 'websockets.legacy"